# Place a column vector surrounded by square brackets in a 3-column table?

Tags: tables, multicol, brackets

I have a 3 column table and in the third column I am representing a $20\times 1$ vector. I would like to put square brackets on each side of this vector.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}

\RequirePackage[left=37mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{libertine} 
\RequirePackage[small,bf]{caption}
\RequirePackage[labelsep=space,tableposition=top]{caption} 
\usepackage{subfig}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ph]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{| >{$}c<{$} | >{$}c<{$} | >{$}c<{$} |}
    \hline
    \text{Position} & \text{State} & \text{P} \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{-2} 
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 0}   & 0 \\
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 1}   & 0 \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 0}  & 0 \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 1}  & 0 \\
    \hhline{--~}
    \multirow{4}{*}{-1} 
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 0}   & 0 \\
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 1}   & 0 \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 0}  & 0 \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 1}  & 0 \\
    \hhline{--~}
    \multirow{4}{*}{0} 
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 0}   & 1 \\
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 1}   & 0 \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 0}  & 0 \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 1}  & 0 \\
    \hhline{--~}
    \multirow{4}{*}{1} 
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 0}   & 0 \\
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 1}   & 0 \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 0}  & 0 \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 1}  & 0 \\
    \hhline{--~}
    \multirow{4}{*}{2} 
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 0}   & 0 \\
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 1}   & 0 \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 0}  & 0 \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 1}  & 0 \\
    \hline    
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Interpretation of the particle matrix for a $1$-step memory walk. Observe that for each position we are able
  to represent the p}
  \label{T:peak}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Does any one know how to place square brackets on either side of the vector P?

Comment: Square brackets would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objective may be achieved by (a) breaking up the `tabular` environment into two separate `array` environments that are placed side by side and (b) placing the column vector that's surrounded by square brackets in the second `array`, which consists of a single column. (Why `array` instead of `tabular`? Because the material being typeset, other than the header row, is all math-related; using an `array` seems more natural.) The second `array` environment contains (i) a header row and (ii) a nested `array` environment containing the 20-element vector, surrounded by square brackets. Note the use of `[0.4pt]` of extra spacing after every fourth row of the column vector: This allows for the width of `\hline`, which equals (you guessed it) `0.4pt`.

I've set the spacing of the square brackets around the column vector deliberately rather tight. If you'd like a bit more space, you could replace the instruction `\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}` with, say, `\begin{array}{@{\hspace{1pt}}c@{\hspace{1pt}}}`.

Finally, since I don't have access to the `PhDThesisPSnPDF` document class, I substituted in the `article` class.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{article}   
\RequirePackage[left=37mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{libertine} 
\RequirePackage[small,bf,labelsep=space,
    tableposition=top]{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{subfig,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,braket}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  $  % start math mode
  \begin{array}{| c | c |}
  \hline
    \text{Position} & \text{State}  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{$-$2} 
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 0}   \\
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 1}   \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 0}  \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 1}  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{$-$1} 
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 0}   \\
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 1}   \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 0}  \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 1}  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{0} 
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 0}   \\
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 1}   \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 0}  \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 1}  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{1} 
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 0}   \\
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 1}   \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 0}  \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 1}  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{2} 
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 0}   \\
    & \ket{\leftarrow, 1}   \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 0}  \\
    & \ket{\rightarrow, 1}  \\
  \hline    
  \end{array}% no separation between the two arrays
  \begin{array}{c|}
  \hline
  \text{P}\\ 
  \hline
    \left[ \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\[0.4pt]  
    0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\[0.4pt] 
    1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\[0.4pt]   
    0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\[0.4pt]   
    0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\  
    \end{array}\right] \\ 
  \hline
  \end{array} 
  $  % end of math mode
  \caption{Interpretation of the particle matrix for a $1$-step memory walk. 
      Observe that for each position we are able to represent the p}
  \label{T:peak}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @sonicboom - Thanks! By the way, I didn't mention this explicitly in the main part of the answer, but you may want to get rid of all vertical lines that separate the columns. Why? Because their thickness (`0.4pt`) is noticeably different from that of the square brackets that surround the vector in the third column. You can get rid of the vertical lines by defining the two "outer" arrays as `\begin{array}{cc}` and `\begin{array}{c}`, resp.